# Find Results within Date range Using Mongo NamedQuery

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I want to find the Results based on Mongo NamedQuery

```
    @Document(collection="test")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class TestData {

        @Id
        private String name;

        private String fiscalWeek;

        private String fiscalYear;

    }
```

Here fisaclWeek in the range of 1 to 52

```
@Query("'fiscalWeek' : {$gt : ?0, $lt : ?1}}")
List<TestData> findByDateRange(String fromDate, String toDate);
```

here fromDate and toDate will come like this **512015** that means concatenation of week and year

I tried like the above way but need to concatenate fisaclWeek and fisaclYear but not sure how to concatenate in the @Query method

How to write a Query here so that I will get results in the range of fromDate and toDate?

Can anyone help on this.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. When you say fromDate and toDate come in the form _512015_, the concatenation of week and year, do you mean that's how they're stored in the database? Or is that the string which is passed into the function at runtime?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just split the `from/toDate` and pass in 4 parameters, i.e. `List<TestData> findByDateRange(String fromFiscalYear, String fromFiscalWeek, String toFiscalYear, String toFiscalWeek)`?